# Detail tags can be closed with click outside, but not with a click on the summary tag itself?

Tags: javascript, html, dropdown, html-tag-details

For the following code:

```js
const allDropdowns = document.querySelectorAll(".main-nav__dropdown");

window.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  [...allDropdowns].forEach((dropdown) => (dropdown.open = false));
});
```

```html
<details class="main-nav__dropdown">
  <summary>First</summary>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">First</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Second</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Third</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Fourth</a></li>
  </ul>
</details>

<details class="main-nav__dropdown">
  <summary>Second</summary>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">First</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Second</a></li>
  </ul>
</details>
```

Why don't the dropdowns close whenever I click on the `summary` itself and how can I get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

### Update

Changed the `click` event over to `mousedown` so far so good

**Figure A**

```
document.addEventListener('mousedown', closeDD);
```

I think it's because the event handler will listen for all click events on the window, that includes all `<summary>`s so there's a conflict. Every click on a `<summary>` will trigger two event handlers:

1. The event handler on window closing all `<details>`.
2. The built in toggle it has as default which opens and closes it's parent `<details>`.

The way accordions are usually made is with it's button *outside* of the content box that collapses and expands. With a nested button as is with `<details>` and `<summary>`, a click event becomes problematic when you want to add extra event handlers to do different things. I think that's the reason why the ["toggle"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDetailsElement/toggle_event) event was added to the [HTMLDetailsElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDetailsElement) interface. It triggers right after a `<details>` opens or closes.

In the example below, there are two event handlers:

| Event Handler | Event | Listener | Purpose |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `closeDD(e)` | `mousedown` | `document` | When the user clicks anywhere all `<details>` will close |
| `checkDD(e)` | `toggle` | all `<details>` | If user clicked a `<summary>` then it's index was recorded and once all `<details>` have been closed by `closeDD()`. The `<details>` that was recorded will be reopened if it was closed originally. |

Aside from the behavior previously described, as a side effect, mutual exclusivity has been implemented as well -- basically only one `<details>` can be open at one time.

I forgot to add one of the most important fixes, is that `pointer-events` is disabled on the active `<summary>` and re-enabled when it's `<details>` is closed. For the life of me I can't resolve the click conflict completely so when a `<details>` is open, it'll look like the click on the `<summary>` works but in reality it's the `<details>` that's reacting to the click.

***Details are commented in example***

```js
// Collect all <details> in an array
const allDD = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("details"));
// Define a flag outside of function
let status = -1;
// Bind document to the mousedown event
document.addEventListener('mousedown', closeDD);

function closeDD(e) {
  // Enable pointer-events on each <summary>
  allDD.forEach(dd => dd.firstElementChild.style.pointerEvents = 'auto');
  // Reference the tag that the user clicked
  const active = e.target;
  /*
  If the tag the user clicked is a <summary> AND it's parent <details>
  is [open]...
  ...Find the index of that <details> and assign it to the status flag
  */
  if (active.matches('summary') && !active.parentElement.hasAttribute('open')) {
    status = allDD.indexOf(active.parentElement);
  }
  // Next, close all <details>
  allDD.forEach(dd => dd.open = false);
}
// Bind all <details> to the toggle event
allDD.forEach(dd => dd.ontoggle = checkDD);

function checkDD(e) {
  // The current <details> tag
  const active = e.target;
  // Find it's index
  let position = allDD.indexOf(active);
  /*
  If the index matches the flag...
  ...The <details> opens...
  ...Disable pointer-events on <summary>
  */
  if (status === position) {
    active.open = true;
    active.firstElementChild.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
  }
  // Rest flag
  status = -1;
}
```

```css
details {
  outline: 5px solid blue;
}

summary {
  outline: 3px dashed red;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>First</summary>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="https://example.com">First</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://example.com">Second</a></li>
  </ul>
</details>

<details>
  <summary>Second</summary>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="https://example.com">First</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://example.com">Second</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://example.com">Third</a></li>
  </ul>
</details>

<details>
  <summary>Third</summary>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="https://example.com">First</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://example.com">Second</a></li>       
    <li><a href="https://example.com">Third</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://example.com">Fourth</a></li>
  </ul>
</details>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! However, that code is really not easy to understand for a beginner like me. I know that you would usually use a button to toggle the dropdown menu, but I thought semantically it would be much better to use the matching tag that is provided in HTML.

Comment: Also: sometimes the closing mechanism with the summary tags still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I left it totally tested it worked great...I comeback to it and it's back to *"sometimes"* working.  Try your right mouse button, for some reason my right mouse button works perfectly (aside from the occasional content menu popping up.)

Comment: @Thilo, see update.